# VSCode's terminal override environment variables in WSL with the hosts' configurations

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open terminal in vscode which connected to a wsl distro, the environment variables are overridden.
For example, when I run `echo $PATH`, the output is vscode contains paths to `C:\Program Files\...`! However if I run the same command in the same distro using Windows Terminal, the output is correct.

How could this happened? How can I stop this?

edit:
attached screenshot
[image: screenshot]

Comment: I just conducted a test of this on my pc, and I have `/mnt/c/*` entries in PATH in both cases. I assume that is a part of WSL. Are you sure you haven't missed anything? Perhaps try running a fresh terminal in both cases, and make sure you run `echo "$PATH"` with quotes, unlike how you specified in your question. (In some cases, your way might confuse the shell parser)

Comment: @abel1502 I tried restart my PC but still no luck. The PATH variable append paths from host OS. And the other variables like `DEVKITPRO` are disappeared from the WSL distro. Before I ran into this situation, I got an update of vscode server.

Comment: Okay, sorry, then I have no other ideas